# Query with row_number() taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have around 90k records in my DB and I run this query:

It takes too much time (around 4 seconds):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By DocumentID desc) peta_rn, peta_query.* From 
    (
            Select   d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) as LatestStatusDatetime, 
                    dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID,d.DocumentID) as CanChangeStatus, d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID,ig.Abbreviation as IGroupAbbreviation, 
                    u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                    it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,
                    dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID) as FlatDocumentName 
                    From Documents d Inner Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
                            Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
                            Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
                            Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                            Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                            Inner Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID                           
    ) as peta_query) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>12000 AND peta_rn<=12100
```

However this 2nd query executes in 1 second:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    peta_query.* From 
    (
            Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By d.DocumentID desc) peta_rn, d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) as LatestStatusDatetime, 
                    dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID,d.DocumentID) as CanChangeStatus, d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID,ig.Abbreviation as IGroupAbbreviation, 
                    u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                    it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,
                    dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID) as FlatDocumentName 
                    From Documents d Inner Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
                            Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
                            Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
                            Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                            Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                            Inner Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID                           
    ) as peta_query) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>12000 AND peta_rn<=12100
```

My questions are:

**1)** Can you please suggest why would my 1st query take so long to execute? I want to optimize my 1st query because it is generated by one of the automated program (whose source I do have but I can't move the RowNumber inside Select).

**2)** The time to execute this is also dependent on the peta_rn. If I give peta_rn > 50000 and peta_rn <= 50100, it takes hopeless amount of time to execute. Can you please also suggest why would the time to execute depend upon the row that I am trying to fetch since ultimately I am only trying to fetch 100 rows at a time.

Comment: have you index peta_rn? it will improve your query performance.

Comment: @habibillah: How should I index peta_rn? It is just an calculated field which is * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By d.DocumentID desc)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the fun of it - can you try this CTE and see how it performs?? I don't totally understand why you have three nested subqueries there....

```
;WITH PetaQuery AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.DocumentID DESC) peta_rn, 
        d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, 
        dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) as LatestStatusDatetime, 
        dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID,d.DocumentID) as CanChangeStatus, 
        d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID,ig.Abbreviation as IGroupAbbreviation, 
        u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
        it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,
        dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID) as FlatDocumentName 
    FROM 
        Documents d 
    INNER JOIN 
        IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID                           
) 
SELECT * FROM PetaQuery
WHERE peta_rn > 12000 AND peta_rn <= 12100
```

Does this have the same response time as your original query?

If so, please check:

- do you have indexes on all your foreign keys (`IGroupID`, `ITypeID`, `UserID`, `DocumentStatusID`, `DocumentID`, `JurisdictionID`)? That is crucial for fast JOIN performance

Comment: This one takes 2 seconds (after I fix few errors like using PetaQuery instead of peta_query and using d.DocumentID instead of DocumentID. No, I don't have indexes on foreign keys. Let me do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can you please suggest why would the execution time depend upon peta_rn? If I have peta_rn > 52000 AND peta_rn <= 52100 in your query it takes 4 seconds. Is row_number itself so inefficient?

Comment: @Jack: check the two execution plans! They tend to tell you a lot about how things are working and what's going on ... I don't think it's `row_number()` that's to blame - more likely your many many `LEFT OUTER JOIN` .....